# Django/Python serve files from URL as http proxy fast stream

Tags: python, django, http, proxy, twisted

We are having a cross-domain issue with SVG files that are being served from a CDN (content delivery network) and therefore are coming from a different domain name than our primary domain which is a Python/Django application. We'd like to setup a special view that can serve as a server-side proxy for these SVG files to mask the domain name and get around the cross-domain issue. The question is how to make a fast http request to a url for static files like SVG or even other types (.jpg, .js, .png, .mp4, etc.) and serve them in a chunked streaming http response as fast as we receive the chunks from the request stream.

We realize it may be faster of course to do this outside of Django and WSGI, perhaps the [twisted server](http://twistedmatrix.com) would be better, so ultimately we are looking for the fastest/best Python method of accomplishing what we need. Really looking for example code for recommended solutions.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you deploy Django on Apache, nginx, or something else?

Comment: Served as a WSGI app via Apache, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put nginx in front of Apache, which will have various benefits such as better static file serving (IOW have it handle static files instead of Apache) and isolating Apache/mod_wsgi from slow clients. Having done that, you could then possibly have your Django app generate X-Accel-Redirect headers which nginx will interpret and issue a new sub request. The target URL for that sub request could be a proxy definition setup in nginx to fetch the files from the CDN and return them as if they were in response to the original request.

Comment: Graham, you're the man. This answer just helped me solve a problem I was having serving static content via CloudFront/S3, with an auth server (generating signed URLs) written in Flask sitting between client and content. Adding X-Accel-Redirect header + rewrite + proxy_pass == applicationCache doesn't barf on my manifest anymore.

Answer (score 1):

So I have a couple of possible solutions for you.  The first one is python, but that might not be your best option.

1) Twisted ships with a [reverse proxy server](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.web.proxy.ReverseProxy.html) in `twisted.web.proxy`.  There's a pretty simple (but effective) example [on their site](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/examples/reverse-proxy.py)

2) Depending on the application (e.g., modern browser) adding CORS response headers in your CDN configuration may work for you.  To check, does your application (browser?) attempt to make the GET request for the SVG resource (with an "Origin: " http header), but then refuse to render it?

If so, you may be tripping your browsers' same-origin requirements.  An origin can relax this requirement by returning `Cross-Domain-Allow-Origin: *` or similar headers along with the response to HTTP requests with an `Origin:` header.

Depending on the CDN, I can possibly clarify / provide example metadata to enable CORS response headers for cross-origin requests

3) Do you absolutely need to use python as a reverse proxy?  Both [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) have very well-tested modules for implementing streaming reverse proxies without the use of Python.  Trying to do this with python might be fun and/or admirable, but it won't scale nearly as well to the same performance levels as doing it directly within your HTTP server

Comment: As you mentioned, you're running under wsgi.  So, for the twisted example to work, you'd probably need to run it on a different port (than 80) and reconfigure apache to forward requests under a given path to it.

Twisted doesn't really play too nicely with wsgi.